# E-mail subscription titles and content should use proper pluralisation

Tags: bug, status-completed, email-notification, plurals

Just received the following e-mail, quickly looked at the title and saw "new items in your Stack Exchange inbox" - at a closer look, it turns out there was just one new item in my inbox, so it shouldn't say "1 new items". Same thing goes for the content, where it says "The following items were added [...]".

Here's a screenshot with the problems highlighted:

[image: "1 new items" message]

It should be a fairly easy thing to fix and it just seems like something that should've been done a long time ago, especially considering the site's technical aspects.

Comment: https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105 (Jeff Atwood is one of the founders of the site :)

Comment: LOL, he's more than welcome to come to my house. Doesn't change the fact that it's a pretty simple thing to fix, and - like I said - really should be fixed given the technical aspects of the site :-)

Comment: The highlighting! It burns my eyes! (could you use FHRC instead?)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236797/162511

Comment: @Undo: FHRC added!

Answer (score 2):

Those emails are now correctly pluralized. The issue was that the inbox notification emails are sent from stackauth and the build for that project wasn't entirely wired up with all the latest translation stuff. Consequently the strings didn't show up in the translation UI, and since pluralization is just another en->en translation the plural from the template was used.

Comment: Seems this problem may have returned: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250167/e-mail-from-stack-exchange-with-incorrect-plural