# E-mail from Stack Exchange with incorrect plural

Tags: bug, email, email-notification, plurals

I received an e-mail from Stack Exchange with the title:

> 1 new items in your Stack Exchange inbox

This is incorrect. The correct writing is: "1 new item".

It would be nice to correct this.

Then, the text of the e-mail starts with :

> The following items were added to your Stack Exchange global inbox

There is a plural here too, but here we may accept it (generic sentence, before a list).

Comment: https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208721/e-mail-subscription-titles-and-content-should-use-proper-pluralisation?rq=1 seems to be broken again?

Comment: Just pretend that we have our own version of English, and an S on the end of anything but a mass noun is silent. If we go so far as _to_ pluralize a mass noun, we'll fix it right after we finish eating our cereals.

Comment: There is another problem with the same system, reported here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252969/1-new-items-in-your-stack-exchange-inbox

Comment: @Tim so this is [tag:status-declined]?

Comment: @TimPost With all due respects, this are just being lazy programmers who is not wanting to makes really English good and red. 