# '1 new items in your Stack Exchange inbox'

Tags: bug, notifications, email, plurals

There are ***2*** bug reports in this question:

1. It seems when you receive an email containing an *answer* notification, the subject is:

> 1 new item**s** in your Stack Exchange inbox

but if you receive comments in the email, it is:

> 1 new item in your Stack Exchange inbox

---

2. In the email with the incorrect subject, the beginning of the actual mail is correct, ie:

subject of "1 new item**s** in your Stack Exchange inbox" says "The following item"

but the email with the correct subject, has an incorrect starting, ie:

subject of "1 new item in your Stack Exchange inbox" The following item**s**"

It's a bit weird... Can it be fixed?

Note: [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208721/e-mail-subscription-titles-and-content-should-use-proper-pluralisation) seems to be what I'm talking about but that is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - it must have come back. Also note that that report shows that a plural subject == plural beginning whereas this is saying plural subject == singular beginning and singular subject == plural beginning.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce That report seems to be [tag:status-completed] - the bug must have come back.

Comment: Beware people knocking on your door who are carrying gigantic S-es.

Comment: @Won't will do ;)

Comment: "@Won't will do", is that a double negative, so you wont? Or, is the suppressor on wont mean you will do it? Nrrghh..

Comment: @James That's up to interpretation :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Oh very good... :)

Comment: @James hmmm.. didn't see that - but that post doesn't say about the second bug.

Comment: I know, but looking at the original question (status-completed one) it seems likely the problem is one script or function. So one post should fix all.

Comment: @James possibly... it looks like the posts linked by FishBelowTheIce and you are exactly the same; but this is the same with an extra bug. We'll see :)